# Using dataframe value as an index for a list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and a list set up as follows:

```
index   list_index
sample1  1
sample2  2
sample3  4

values = [-0.5, -23, 0, 15, 100]
```

I am trying to create a new column in the dataframe that takes the list_index and values list. Like the following:

```
index   list_index    val
sample1  1           -23
sample2  2            0
sample3  5            100
```

My code is:

```
df['val'] = values[df['list_index']]
```

I am getting TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices not Series.

Comment: `np.array(values)[df.list_index]`

Answer (score 1):

I would use `pandas.series.apply`

Example code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,3,5]})

v = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]

df['B'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: v[x])
```

Results in what you are looking for I think:

```
Out[7]:
   A  B
0  1  1
1  3  1
2  5  1
```

**For your code would do the below**

`df['val'] = df['list_index'].apply(lambda x: values[x])`

*Essentially you are getting the above error as you are not passing in the indices of the list element by element but rather as a series which does not work.*